# K8S: Can I get my cluster's KUBECONFIG via Google's Kubernetes Engine API? (not via gcloud container clusters get-credentials)

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I'm writing a Node app that's designed to monitor (and patch parts of) a Kubernetes cluster hosted on Google's Kubernetes Engine.

I'd like to do this using the [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client) module, however in order to access the cluster, I need to first supply it with a KUBECONFIG for that cluster. Now I gather that i'd do this locally using the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]` command which would populate my local KUBECONFIG file for me.

However is there a way to do this using Google's Kubernetes Engine API, within my NodeJS app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way on how to achieve GKE API connection from [godaddy/kubernetes-client](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client) as not much information is available in this project, developed by community enthusiasts. Seems it requires `kubectl proxy` to be enabled on GKE side to get authorized with Kubernetes [REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api), which was confirmed by some [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751880/python-or-node-access-to-gke-kubectl) contributors. However, it's feasible to manage connection to GKE API with Go and Python via appropriate plugins as described [here](https://ahmet.im/blog/gke-api/).

I would search something more about the other NodeJS client libraries, like: [github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client](https://github.com/Goyoo/node-k8s-client) or [github.com/tenxcloud/node-kubernetes-client](https://github.com/tenxcloud/node-kubernetes-client).